# Is it possible to gain complete remote access of another Android phone from my phone?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, remote-access

In my phone (Samsung Galaxy On7, Android 6.0.1-Marshmallow), the internal memory is very insufficient, and moreover, important apps like MS word and Excel come inbuilt, due to which I cannot move them to the sd card.

I saw on the net that there are methods by which I can gain access over my desktop from my mobile through the Google Chrome Remote Desktop app. There are apps to do the reverse as well. But how can I gain access over another Android phone from my phone?

Actually, I want to use my father's phone, because in his one (Samsung Galaxy On5, Android 6.0.1-Marshmallow), the above stated apps can be moved to sd card. So, it would have been great if I could create documents or spreadsheets from my phone on his phone, and then bring them over to my phone by saving them in the Cloud. In this way, my phone can be saved from unnecessary space loss. I've spoken to him, and he has agreed, but now I need to know how I can do this.

How can I get complete remote access of another device from my device?

*It would be best if I **don't** have to root my phone or that of my father's.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this seems to be achievable at least with the aid of applications such as [TeamViewer](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Connections-From-Mobile-to-Mobile-Devices/ta-p/280)

**Requirements**

> To be able to use this feature, you must meet the following
>   requirements:
>
> - You are using TeamViewer 12
> - You are a private user or own a TeamViewer 12 Premium license (or higher)
>
> **For the supporting device**
>
> - You have installed the latest version of TeamViewer for Remote Control on your Android  device.
>
> **For the supported device**
>
> - You have installed the latest version of [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) on  Android device.
>
> **Setup**
>
> On the supported Android device:
>
> 1. Download and install [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) or [TeamViewer Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market) on the device.
>
>    - You may be prompted to install an AddOn according to your device manufacturer. Please follow the on-screen instructions and install the
>        necessary AddOn for Remote Control capabilities.
> 2. As for every TeamViewer connection, you will need the target device’s TeamViewer ID to connect.
>
> *For QuickSupport : You can find the TeamViewer ID of the device on the start screen of the app.*
>
> **On the supporting device**
>
> 1. Download and install [TeamViewer for Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile) on your Android device. If you already have installed the App on your device,
>      make sure to update to the latest version.
> 2. Open the App on the respective device.
> 3. Connect to the supported device using the ID mentioned above or via the Computers & Contacts list.
>
> Enter the TeamViewer ID of the supported device in the TeamViewer ID
>   field under Connect. To access, click Remote Control.
>
> **After the connections was accepted on the supported device, you are connected to the mobile device and can remotely control the entire
>   device like if would have it holding in your hands.**

Credits

- [Connections From Mobile to Mobile Devices](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Connections-From-Mobile-to-Mobile-Devices/ta-p/280)

Comment: You didn't say this: "Please note, that connections are limited to five minutes each for private users." Which means I've to buy a license. :-(

Comment: Apologies there. Are you looking for a free method of doing that, I m not sure if there is indefinite periods of unattended access, but will update if i get something

Comment: ok, I'll wait, and think over buying a license. Meanwhile, I'll accept your answer,  but if you find anything free, please let me know.

Comment: Sure! and thanks BTW you can always un-accept the answer if better answers are posted,and will let you know if I find ab alternative gratis workaround

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to use your gmail account's free Drive, Docs and Sheets access to create, edit and share your documents without ever storing them on your phone, all you need are the 3 apps in question. That way you don't even have to consider going through all the steps of installing Teamviewer (or a similar program) onto each phone and configuring them to work together at any time. Besides, you will use far less data.

Comment: Sheets, slides and docs use up more space than MS apps. If I could move then to the SD card, then this question would have never risen. Data is not a problem as of now.